# Can the Speed magic-weapon-special-ability add +1 AC modifier as Haste spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, armor-class

Can the [Speed magic-weapon-special-ability](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/speed) add +1 AC modifier as a [Haste](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste) spell does? Here the description:

*When making a full-attack action, the wielder of a speed weapon may make one extra attack with it. The attack uses the wielder’s full base attack bonus, plus any modifiers appropriate to the situation. (This benefit is not cumulative with similar effects, such as a haste spell.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

As you cite, the full text of the [Speed magic weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/speed) states

> When making a full-attack action, **the wielder of a speed weapon may make one extra attack with it**. The attack uses the wielder’s full base attack bonus, plus any modifiers appropriate to the situation. (This benefit is not cumulative with similar effects, such as a *haste* spell.)

The weapon itself only gives you the ability to **make an extra attack with it**. Haste would give you an extra attack, too, but you cannot combine them to get two extra attacks.

[Haste](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste) tells you that it gives you both an extra attack, +1 to hit, and +1 to AC. But the weapon does not mention that it gives you +1 to AC, it only gives you the extra attack.

If you were under the influence of haste, you could however use the +1 to AC haste gives you. Only the benefit that is granted by the weapon, the extra attack, is not cumulative.

Comment: damn, my GM said so.....